# web scraping url in python from <a href>

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape links from the page source.

Here is the part of the page source that I am using:

```
<a class="Fl(end) Mt(3px) Cur(p)" href="https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/GOOG?period1=1578447785&amp;period2=1610070185&amp;interval=1d&amp;events=history&amp;includeAdjustedClose=true" download="GOOG.csv"><svg class="Va(m)! Mend(5px) Stk($linkColor)! Fill($linkColor)! Cur(p)" width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 48 48" data-icon="download" style="fill: rgb(0, 129, 242); stroke: rgb(0, 129, 242); stroke-width: 0; vertical-align: bottom;"><path d="M43.002 43.002h-38c-1.106 0-2.002-.896-2.002-2v-11c0-1.105.896-2 2.002-2 1.103 0 1.998.895 1.998 2v9h34.002v-9c0-1.105.896-2 2-2s2 .895 2 2v11c0 1.103-.896 2-2 2m-19-8L11.57 23.307c-.75-.748-.75-1.965 0-2.715.75-.75 1.965-.75 2.715 0l7.717 7.716V2h4v26.308l7.717-7.716c.75-.75 1.964-.75 2.714 0s.75 1.967 0 2.715L24.002 35.002z"></path></svg><span>Download</span></a>
```

So what I basically tried to do was to extract the url link after "href"

Here is what I did but it didnt work out. The output was just []. It would be appreciated if I can get help

```
hist = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(urlHist).text, 'lxml')
stockHist = hist.find_all('a',{'class': 'Fl(end) Mt(3px) Cur(p)'})
```

I am using BautifulSoup and urlHist is the url of the given page.

```
urlHist = "https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?p=GOOG&.tsrc=fin-srch"
```

Comment: Please make this a [mcve]. What is it doing right now?

Comment: The URL starts and ends with a double quote. put the line into a file, say 'myline' then use sed to extract the URL like this ```sed -e 's/.*https/https/' -e 's/".*//' myline```

Answer (score 0):

Your output gets a list, of tags, of all "a" tags with a class of "Fl(end) Mt(3px) Cur(p)". From that list, you need to find the one that matches what you're looking for in some other way (or if there will always only be one, replace find_all with find), and put ["href"] as the index value. For example:

```
for hist in stockHist:
    if hist.get_text() == "Download":
        url = hist["href"]
```

Comment: my current program is producing an empty list :(

Comment: Can you provide urlHist, I made the line you provided into a html file and it worked. Also, make sure you are actually getting a valid return from yahoo, they limit page views by hiding data, not returning http errors.

Comment: https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?p=GOOG it is this one

Comment: Check the requests text in python, your link isn't there. It's added in by a script after the page load.

Comment: I dont get what you mean

Comment: print your hist variable, you'll see the link you're looking for isn't there

Answer (score 0):

Using css selectors, try

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# assuming you have lxml installed and urlHist is set somewhere
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(urlHist).content, 'lxml')
# select the a tag whose text contains the word Download
t = soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("Download")')
# get the href attribute
desired_url = t.get('href')
```

If you are using an old version of bs4/SoupSieve you might have to do

```py
soup.select_one('a:contains("Download")')
```

Here are the [docs](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:-soup-contains) for the selector I used

Comment: when i print this -> soup.select_one('a:contains("Download")'), it is returning None :(

Comment: Looking at the page you linked I don't think you'll be able to scrape the data from it with just requests and bs4. Like the download link the table is loaded dynamically. That is to say it's not actually in the plain html, it's added later by Javascript or the like. This sort of content is ignored by bs4. I suggest looking for an API alternative or searching for something like scrape a dynamically loaded page with Python.